# Quarkus test database seeding

Tags: quarkus

Is there any Quarkus-native mechanism for database seeding/comparing or is e.g. Database Rider compatible with the general Q-lifecycle for this? Didn't see any mention of this in the testing guide?

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Comment: Have you tried the `import.sql` mechanism?

Comment: I saw a blog where this was used but it looked a bit cumbersome in situations where you'd like to seed/compare a test-specific dataset, compared to e.g. Database Rider which are annotation-based and you can easily see which datasets are referenced. And I'm not sure if it was orm-specific or could be used in a generic JDBC scenario.

Comment: I have never used Database Rider so I can't comment

Answer (score 1):

I use either [Instancio](https://www.instancio.org/user-guide/) or Liquibase as follows:

> %tst.quarkus.liquibase.change-log=db/test-data.xml

And in test-data.xml, I also include a csv import (besides the other changelog files) which contains test data.

However, my preference goes for Instancio because much easier to setup and your tests become also clearer.

```
@Test
@TestTransaction
public void bulkDataTest() {
    var entities = Instancio.of(MyEntity.class).size(1000).create();
    MyEntity.persistAll(entities);  
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got around to testing it, Apparently is works mostly OOTB just by adding some
@DBUnit, @DBRider, @DataSet and @ExpectedDataSet (and a JDBC connection) and adding rider-junit5 to pom.xml.

Seeding and comparing works with json-files in the test/resources folder! DB-seed, REST-call validation, DB-compare and cleanup in ~400ms...